# How to echo an array in PHP

Tags: php, api

How can I in an API echo results in a new array?

example:

```
 echo implode('[]',$resultArray);
```

result:

> $resultArray

requested result:

> [$resultArray]

Comment: will array_merge work? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)?

Comment: `var_dump or print_r` is it in php side?

Comment: What do you mean by echo results in a new array?  What are the results?  Are you consuming an API?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're implementing an API the best pracrice will be to output your results in a format that's readable and understandable by multiple programming languages. JSON is the way to go. Read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [here](http://www.json.org/)

To echo an array, or anything not just an array, in PHP in a JSON format use:

`echo json_encode($data);`

where $data holds the output

Answer (score 1):

`echo json_encode($resultArray);`

Assuming you want to keep the data in the response an array to the requester.

If not, your example will work but I'd suggest something easy to parse on the requester's side like a CSV value using commas: `echo implode(',', $resultArray);`

if you're looking to output the string `'[$resultArray]'`, it'll be something like `echo '[$'.print_var_name($resultArray).']'`.  Not sure why you'd need it like this, but your question is a little bit vague/confusing on exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($array); echo "</pre>";
```

This way you will get a nice preformatted result of var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($resultArray), true);
```

or

```
Print_r();
```